# Detect new content loaded in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a custom "nickname-highlighter" just for me, on a distant and javascript based webchat. Clearly, I want that each time my nickname appears in the chat, a sound is played.

In this chat there is a #TheChatDiv in which a new .NewChatText is added each time a user write something new.

So far I've tried this :

```
$('#TheChatDiv').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
 // Do things, like play the song of your people.
});
```

Which actually works well, except that i'm unable to extract the text of the chat posted. The thing is that I also need to read the text posted, to detect my nickname in it and make my code behave like it needs to.

Any idea how I could do that ?

Comment: what is the structure of your .NewChatText element?

Comment: This is <span class="NewChatText"><span class="date">date</span><span class="nickname">MyNick</span><span class="message">The MEssage</span></span>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should generally create an event or fire a function whenever a message is inserted into the chat element and then search the added message for whatever you're looking for, however if that's not an option you'd generally be better of using mutation observers instead of the deprecated DOMSubtreeModified event, something like this

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  $.each(mutations, function(_, mutation) {
      $.each(mutation.addedNodes, function(_, node) {
          if ( $(node).text().indexOf('Cyc') != -1) {
              // Play sound for Cyc
          }
      });
  });    
});

observer.observe(
    $('#TheChatDiv').get(0), 
    { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true }
);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nBD89/1/)

Comment: This is a very clever way to do it ! However, I didn't work for me, I don't know why. The each(mutations, function(_,mutation){ works, but not the addedNodes.

Comment: After some testing, it appears that the detected mutation.type is "attribute" which is weird because I really see a new <span> with the new chat message.

Comment: I finally managed to get it working. Thank you very much for you idea !

Answer (score 0):

As for me the better way is to inject highlighting logic directly in your `receiveMessage` function where `NewChatText` is being created and appended to the `TheChatDiv`.
I assume you have something like:

```
function receiveMessage(message) {
    var chat = $('#TheChatDiv');
    $('<div>')
        .text(message)
        .addClass('NewChatText')
        .appendTo(chat);

    if (message.indexOf('YourNickName') {
        // Play sound, highlight etc.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var nickname = $('.NewChatText .nickname').text();
if (nickname == 'YOURNAME') {
   // Insert your code here, the autor of .NewChatText is 'YOURNAME'
}
```

*If this isn't the response you are searching for, you should describe your problem more in detail.*

Comment: `contains()` checks if a DOM element is a descendant of another DOM element. You where probably thinking of the `:contains` selector, but they are quite different.

Comment: My bad, its contains in the other programming languages, in JS its 's.indexOf("oo") != -1'